# Where is the ground reference when using a thermocouple?

Tags: temperature, multiplexer, thermocouple

I am using a [MAX31856](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX31856.pdf) to read thermocouple voltages. I have an [ADG707](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG706_707.pdf) differential multiplexer feeding the MAX31856 from various ungrounded thermocouple probes (see diagram below). I am using the multiplexer in single sided mode (Vdd = 3.3v, Vss = gnd).

Sometimes the Maxium chip can read the theromocouple and other times it cannot. However, when I take the mux out, everything works correctly. My first guess is that this has something to do with the thermocouple not sharing the same ground reference as the multiplexer. **My concern is that since the thermocouple lines are floating relative to the mux power supply, they may be floating in and out of range of the mux inputs.** Is this correct or is there something else fundamently wrong with this configuration? If it is a floating ground issue, how can I remedy it.

[image]

Comment: Have you connected the bias pin to one of the inputs as per the Maxim data sheet?

Comment: Sorry, I may have over-simplified the schematic. I do have the bias pin connected. I am using a eval board this [schematic](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/035/946/original/sensors_schem.png?1474583748).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem with my circuit design. The issue was a cold solder joint.

Answer (score 2):

You **do** need to connect the bias pin to the -T input to set up the input correctly: -

[image]

You also need to run both chips from a common 0 volt rail (AGND on MAX31856 connects to Vss on ADG707 multiplexer).

You also need to ensure that your address timing is correct and that you give the MAX31856 enough time for the input/multiplexer to settle prior to reading the value. Sometimes, on open circuit thermocouple inputs to a multiplexer like this, it can take a little longer to settle.

Comment: Sorry, I may have over-simplified the schematic. I do have the bias pin connected. I am using a eval board this [schematic](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/035/946/original/sensors_schem.png?1474583748).

Comment: Also, my AGND and Vss are tied to the same ground from my power supply

Comment: I've added an extra paragraph.

Comment: I have already tried that. I just tied the A0..A2 pins to ground and tested in a static configuration without any switching. That did not help.

Comment: So, what was the faulty reading you got and what did you expect to see?

Comment: What connects to EN on the mux?

Comment: the EN on the mux is tied to 3.3V. I will provide a more detailed schematic this evening.

Comment: My concern is that since the thermocouple lines are floating relative to the mux power supply, they may be floating in and out of range of the mux inputs. Is this a valid concern?

Answer (score -1):

I was using the 31856 in an application for very high current ovens, and experienced serious ground loop issues in which the 31856 ***DID*** drift in and out of range.  This issue was solved by isolating the 31856 and it's power supply using the ISOW7842.  This completely resolved the issue.